# CakePHP 3.7 Url is adding to query String

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

Using cakephp 3.7 when clicked on the Navigation bar New url is added to query string of the Params, Here is the result

Link should redirect user to

```
http://merchant1.com/users/gallery
```

but in the browser address bar below it actually, redirect to

```
http://merchant1.com/users/merchant?redirect=%2Fhqusers%2Fgallery
```

Here is the Debug result of $this->request->params

```
Array (
    [controller] => users
    [action] => merchant
    [pass] => Array
        (
        )

    [plugin] => 
    [_matchedRoute] => /:controller/:action/*
    [?] => Array
        (
            [redirect] => /users/gallery
        )

    [_ext] => 
    [isAjax] =>  
)
```

Below is Auth config

```
$this->Auth->config([   
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [                     
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ],
            'userModel' => 'Users'
        ]                           
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'logout'
    ],              
    'storage' => [
        'className' => 'Session',
        'key' => 'Auth.users'
    ]
]);
```

What is wrong here.

Comment: I don't see what your Auth config would have to do with this, bit it's unclear what your problem is. You are using the array shown to generate a URL, and the resulting link isn't what you expect? Because what you're saying is showing in the address bar is precisely what I'd expect to be generated based on that array. So, I'm not sure whether you've greatly misunderstood how it works, or if you just haven't explained the scenario clearly.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I edit the question, Issue is the when I click on Navigation bar The new url on which page should redirect is added to query string of current page Url, for same I displayed the $this->request_param result.

Comment: Still unclear. The navigation bar is part of your page? And the URL in the link you're clicking on (from view source, for example) is what, exactly?

Comment: @GregSchmidt This is how I create navigation link in the view page
 echo $this->Html->link('Gallery', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'gallery'));
But when I click on this link, New url get added to current page url as a query string
http://merchant1.com/users/merchant?redirect=%2Fhqusers%2Fgallery

Comment: Okay, that's clearer now. :-) Controller names should be capitalized, but I don't know if that's the problem. In the HTML source for the initial page (before you click the link), what URL do you see in the Gallery link?

Comment: @GregSchmidt it is http://merchant1.com/users/gallery on the hover of the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for the above issue

I have to replaced

> $this->Auth->allow('gallery')

to

> $this->Auth->allow(['gallery'])

in the beforeFilter method of the controller.